# How can I use basename with parallel?

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel, basename

I have files like this on a Linux system:

```
    10S1_S5_L002_chrm.fasta  SRR3184711_chrm.fasta    SRR3987378_chrm.fasta  SRR4029368_chrm.fasta  SRR5204465_chrm.fasta    SRR5997546_chrm.fasta
13_S7_L003_chrm.fasta    SRR3184712_chrm.fasta    SRR3987379_chrm.fasta  SRR4029369_chrm.fasta  SRR5204520_chrm.fasta    SRR5997547_chrm.fasta
14_S8_L003_chrm.fasta    SRR3184713_chrm.fasta    SRR3987380_chrm.fasta  SRR4029370_chrm.fasta  SRR5208699_chrm.fasta    SRR5997548_chrm.fasta
17_S4_L002_chrm.fasta    SRR3184714_chrm.fasta    SRR3987415_chrm.fasta  SRR4029371_chrm.fasta  SRR5208700_chrm.fasta    SRR5997549_chrm.fasta
3_S1_L001_chrm.fasta     SRR3184715_chrm.fasta    SRR3987433_chrm.fasta  SRR4029372_chrm.fasta  SRR5208701_chrm.fasta    SRR5997550_chrm.fasta
4_S2_L001_chrm.fasta     SRR3184716_chrm.fasta    SRR3987482_chrm.fasta  SRR4029373_chrm.fasta  SRR5208770_chrm.fasta    SRR5997551_chrm.fasta
50m_S10_L004_chrm.fasta  SRR3184717_chrm.fasta    SRR3987489_chrm.fasta  SRR4029374_chrm.fasta  SRR5208886_chrm.fasta    SRR5997552_chrm.fasta
5_S3_L001_chrm.fasta     SRR3184718_chrm.fasta    SRR3987493_chrm.fasta  SRR4029375_chrm.fasta  SRR5211153_chrm.fasta    SRR6050903_chrm.fasta
65m_S11_L005_chrm.fasta  SRR3184719_chrm.fasta    SRR3987495_chrm.fasta  SRR4029376_chrm.fasta  SRR5211162_chrm.fasta    SRR6050905_chrm.fasta
6_S6_L002_chrm.fasta     SRR3184720_chrm.fasta    SRR3987647_chrm.fasta  SRR4029377_chrm.fasta  SRR5211163_chrm.fasta    SRR6050920_chrm.fasta
70m_S12_L006_chrm.fasta  SRR3184721_chrm.fasta    SRR3987651_chrm.fasta  SRR4029378_chrm.fasta  SRR5215118_chrm.fasta    SRR6050921_chrm.fasta
80m_S1_L002_chrm.fasta   SRR3184722_chrm.fasta    SRR3987657_chrm.fasta  SRR4029379_chrm.fasta  SRR5247122_chrm.fasta    SRR6050958_chrm.fasta
```

In all there are 423
I was asked to cut them in 32 parts for an optimal parallelisation on 32 CPU
So now I have this:

```
    10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-10.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-26.fasta  SRR4029372_chrm.part-22.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-20.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-11.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-27.fasta  SRR4029372_chrm.part-23.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-21.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-12.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-28.fasta  SRR4029372_chrm.part-24.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-22.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-13.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-29.fasta  SRR4029372_chrm.part-25.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-23.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-14.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-2.fasta   SRR4029372_chrm.part-26.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-24.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-15.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-30.fasta  SRR4029372_chrm.part-27.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-25.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-16.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-31.fasta  SRR4029372_chrm.part-28.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-26.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-17.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-32.fasta  SRR4029372_chrm.part-29.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-27.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-18.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-3.fasta   SRR4029372_chrm.part-2.fasta     SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-28.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-19.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-4.fasta   SRR4029372_chrm.part-30.fasta    SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-29.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-1.fasta   SRR3986254_chrm.part-5.fasta   SRR4029372_chrm.part-3.fasta     SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-2.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-20.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-6.fasta   SRR4029372_chrm.part-4.fasta     SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-30.fasta
10S1_S5_L002_chrm.part-21.fasta  SRR3986254_chrm.part-7.fasta   SRR4029372_chrm.part-5.fasta     SRR5581526-1_chrm.part-31.fasta
```

I want to apply a command from the CRISPRCasFinder tool
The command works well when I use it alone on 1 `namefile.fasta`
The command also works well  when I use `parallel` on `namefile.part*.fasta`.

But when I try to make the command more general by using `basename`, nothing works. I want to use `basename` to keep the name of my input files in the output folder.

I tried this on a smaller data set:

```
time parallel 'dossierSortie=$(basename -s .fasta {}) ; singularity exec -B $PWD /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder-release-4.2.20/CrisprCasFinder.simg perl /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/CRISPRCasFinder.pl -so /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/sel392v2.so -cf /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/CasFinder-2.0.3 -drpt /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/supplementary_files/repeatDirection.tsv -rpts /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/supplementary_files/Repeat_List.csv -cas -def G --meta -out /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/Result{} -in /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/{}' ::: *_chrm.part*.fasta
```

And it did this

```
    ERR358546_chrm.part-1.fasta    SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.bck   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.lcp   SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.al1
ERR358546_chrm.part-2.fasta    SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.bwt   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.llv   SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.bck
ERR358546_chrm.part-3.fasta    SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.des   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.ois   SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.bwt
ERR358546_chrm.part-4.fasta    SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.lcp   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.prj   SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.des
ERR358546_chrm.part-5.fasta    SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.llv   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.sds   SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.lcp
ERR358546_chrm.part-6.fasta    SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.ois   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.sti1  SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.llv
ERR358546_k141_26987.fna       SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.prj   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.suf   SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.ois
ERR358546_k141_33604.fna       SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.sds   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.tis   SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.prj
ERR358546_k141_90631.fna       SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.sti1  SRR5100341_k141_10942.fna       SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.sds
ResultERR358546_chrm.part-3    SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.suf   SRR5100341_k141_164.fna         SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.sti1
ResultERR358546_chrm.part-4    SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.tis   SRR5100341_k141_3046.fna        SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.suf
ResultSRR4029114_chrm.part-1   SRR5100341_chrm.part-10.fasta   SRR5100341_k141_3968.fna        SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna.tis
ResultSRR4029114_chrm.part-4   SRR5100341_chrm.part-11.fasta   SRR5100341_k141_631.fna         SRR5100345_k141_4429.fna
ResultSRR5100341_chrm.part-10  SRR5100341_chrm.part-12.fasta   SRR5100341_k141_6376.fna        SRR5100345_k141_4832.fna
ResultSRR5100341_chrm.part-11  SRR5100341_chrm.part-13.fasta   SRR5100341_k141_8699.fna        SRR5100345_k141_6139.fna
ResultSRR5100341_chrm.part-3   SRR5100341_chrm.part-1.fasta    SRR5100341_k141_8892.fna        SRR5100345_k141_731.fna
ResultSRR5100341_chrm.part-9   SRR5100341_chrm.part-2.fasta    SRR5100345_chrm.part-10.fasta   SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.al1
ResultSRR5100345_chrm.part-1   SRR5100341_chrm.part-3.fasta    SRR5100345_chrm.part-1.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.bck
ResultSRR5100345_chrm.part-4   SRR5100341_chrm.part-4.fasta    SRR5100345_chrm.part-2.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.bwt
ResultSRR5100345_chrm.part-9   SRR5100341_chrm.part-5.fasta    SRR5100345_chrm.part-3.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.des
SRR4029114_chrm.part-1.fasta   SRR5100341_chrm.part-6.fasta    SRR5100345_chrm.part-4.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.lcp
SRR4029114_chrm.part-2.fasta   SRR5100341_chrm.part-7.fasta    SRR5100345_chrm.part-5.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.llv
SRR4029114_chrm.part-3.fasta   SRR5100341_chrm.part-8.fasta    SRR5100345_chrm.part-6.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.ois
SRR4029114_chrm.part-4.fasta   SRR5100341_chrm.part-9.fasta    SRR5100345_chrm.part-7.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.prj
SRR4029114_chrm.part-5.fasta   SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna       SRR5100345_chrm.part-8.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.sds
SRR4029114_k141_14384.fna      SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.al1   SRR5100345_chrm.part-9.fasta    SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.sti1
SRR4029114_k141_16765.fna      SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.bck   SRR5100345_k141_1211.fna        SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.suf
SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna      SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.bwt   SRR5100345_k141_2884.fna        SRR5100345_k141_731.fna.tis
SRR4029114_k141_23527.fna.al1  SRR5100341_k141_10416.fna.des   SRR5100345_k141_3703.fna
```

The names of the folder are not okay because I want for example just `ResultERR358546` and not `ResultERR358546_chrm.part-2.fasta`
And I don't want a result for each part but only for each ID.

Comment: You aren't using your `dossierSortie` variable anywhere. Did you mean to use `-out /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/Result${dossierSortie}`?

Comment: Hi, If I edit my commande with this I have the same result with the wrong name folder and all the temporary files that are normally deleted at the end :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `basename` command only removes the fixed `.fasta` extension - as far as I know it cannot remove a variable pattern.

However GNU `parallel` provides a [Perl expression replacement string](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Perl-expression-replacement-string) facility that is much more powerful than `basename` - ex. given

```
$ ls *_chrm.part*.fasta
ERR358546_chrm.part-2.fasta  ERR358546_chrm.part-5.fasta  ERR358546_chrm.part-8.fasta
ERR358546_chrm.part-3.fasta  ERR358546_chrm.part-6.fasta  ERR358546_chrm.part-9.fasta
ERR358546_chrm.part-4.fasta  ERR358546_chrm.part-7.fasta
```

then

```
$ parallel echo Result'{= s:_.*$:: =}' ::: *_chrm.part*.fasta
ResultERR358546
ResultERR358546
ResultERR358546
ResultERR358546
ResultERR358546
ResultERR358546
ResultERR358546
ResultERR358546
```

where the substitution `s:_.*$::` replaces everything after an underscore with nothing. Transplanting to your original command:

```
time parallel ' 
  singularity exec -B "$PWD" /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder-release-4.2.20/CrisprCasFinder.simg \
  perl /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/CRISPRCasFinder.pl \
  -so /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/sel392v2.so \
  -cf /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/CasFinder-2.0.3 \
  -drpt /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/supplementary_files/repeatDirection.tsv \
  -rpts /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/supplementary_files/Repeat_List.csv \
  -cas -def G --meta \
  -out /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/Result'{= s:_.*$:: =}' \
  -in /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/{}
' ::: *_chrm.part*.fasta
```

---

If you want to capture and include the part index, you could modify the expression to

```
Result'{= s:_chrm\.part-(\d+)\.fasta$:_$1: =}'
```

or

```
'{= s:_chrm\.part-(\d+)\.fasta$:Result_$1: =}'
```

for example.

Answer (score 4):

Your `basename` command only removes the `.fasta`:

```
$ basename ERR358546_chrm.part-1.fasta .fasta
ERR358546_chrm.part-1
```

To get only the sequence name, you need to remove more and since the number after `part` changes, you can't use `basename`. You can, however, use the shell itself and remove everything after the first `_`:

```
$ name="ERR358546_chrm.part-1.fasta"
$ newName="${name%%_*}"
$ echo "$newName"
ERR358546
```

Next, you need to actually use this. You have `dossierSortie=$(basename -s .fasta {})` but you never actually use `$dossierSortie`. Since you are using `parallel`, which will replace `{}` with each of the input file names, you need to first store that as a shell variable and then apply the replacement above:

```
parallel ... 'name="{}"; dossierSortie="${name%%_*}"
```

So, this should do what you want:

```
time parallel 'name={}; dossierSortie="${name%%_*}"; \
     singularity exec -B "$PWD" \
    /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder-release-4.2.20/CrisprCasFinder.simg perl /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/CRISPRCasFinder.pl \
    -so /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/sel392v2.so \
    -cf /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/CasFinder-2.0.3 \
    -drpt /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/supplementary_files/repeatDirection.tsv \
    -rpts /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/supplementary_files/Repeat_List.csv \
    -cas -def G --meta \
    -out /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/Result"${dossierSortie}" \
    -in /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/{}' ::: *_chrm.part*.fasta
```

Or, in case the line breaks trip you up, on a single line:

```
time parallel 'name={}; dossierSortie="${name%%_*}"; singularity exec -B "$PWD" /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder-release-4.2.20/CrisprCasFinder.simg perl /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/CRISPRCasFinder.pl -so /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/sel392v2.so -cf /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/CasFinder-2.0.3 -drpt /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/supplementary_files/repeatDirection.tsv -rpts /usr/local/CRISPRCasFinder/supplementary_files/Repeat_List.csv -cas -def G --meta -out /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/Result"${dossierSortie}" -in /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_CRISPRCasFinder/Test/{}' ::: *_chrm.part*.fasta
```